# Should an iphone app communicate directly with a cassandra backend?

Tags: ios, json, cassandra

Obviously there are multiple steps and phases of implementing such a thing.

I was thinking I would eventually have a webserver that takes http json requests from the ios app, and then queries the cassandra backend and sends results back. I could load balance and all that fancy stuff still, and also provide a logical layer on server side, and keep the client app lightweight.

I'm not sure i understand how cassandra clients fit though. It seems like the cassandra objective c client could eliminate the need for the above approach.

I saw another question and answer but it wasnt clear, perhaps because it varys on the need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An iPhone app should not directly connect to a Cassandra backend or any other DB store.

First of all, talking to a database often requires adapting a very specific binary protocol (for Cassandra in particular, binary CQL or Thrift).  Writing an adapter that would let your Objective-C app communicate in this binary protocol is a *major* piece of work, and could easily cost more than the rest of your app in effort.  If you hide the DB behind a web-server, however, you will be able to select from a variety of existing adapters available in different server-side languages, meaning that you don't need to redo all that low-level work.  You'll only be responsible for a relatively small piece of server-side code that would translate your REST queries and forward them to one of the Cassandra adapters (which expose easy-to-use interfaces).

Secondly, if you wanted to connect to a remote database from the phone, your database server would have to open its ports to the internet at large, which is a very bad security practice, even if you use SSL and user credentials.  Again, if you hide behind a web server, you will be putting in a layer of technology that has evolved for decades to remain secure on the public internet.

Finally, having your phone talk to Cassandra directly is a poor architectural pattern.  When you write apps that communicate on the internet, you want them to know as little as possible about each other, only how to talk to each other (preferably in a standard protocol).  That way you can replace or upgrade individual components while keeping everything else the same.  This may not sound like a lot, but is actually the main reason why phones, or web browsers, don't directly talk to databases.  (If this setup were a good idea in principle, the first two problems could be easily solved given enough engineering effort.)

---

The approach you first suggested with JSON and the web server is the only correct way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like RESTful API, there are many reasons for that.
if your servers ip addresses change you have to update all client, if you add more nodes you will need to update all clients, if you decide to upgrade your cassandra and some functions change your clients will break and you need to update all clients.